# sorting previous data with any row

Tags: sql, oracle11g

i have following data accordingly

```
Asset Link
100 
101 100
102 101
103 102
104 103
105 104
```

My requirement is that if i pass any value to `Asset` column it should return all previous and future history of a asset movement ,
FOr example
if Pass `103` to `Asset` column it should return below data by linking values with `link_to` column

```
101 100
102 101
103 102
104 103
105 104
```

Please suggest any useful solution

Thanks

Comment: Please tag you question with the version of Oracle you are using.

Answer (score 0):

First part is for historical movement, second for future, `union` is to merge them:

```
select * from data 
  where link is not null
  connect by prior link = asset start with asset = 103
union 
select * from data 
  connect by prior asset = link start with asset = 103
```

Test:

```
create table data (asset number(4), link number(4));
insert into data values (100, null);
insert into data values (101, 100);
insert into data values (102, 101);
insert into data values (103, 102);
insert into data values (104, 103);
insert into data values (105, 104);
insert into data values (205, 214);

ASSET  LINK
----- -----
  101   100
  102   101
  103   102
  104   103
  105   104
```